# Help Identifying Chip, How to read from it

Tags: microchip

[image: YL9000H HGY2021P]

Hello, This is the chip on the Roku Remote RC280J, and I can't find any data sheets or information about it at all.
As well, I am not even sure how to read any of the data from the chip as well.

If anyone would be able to educate me any farther than I have got I would be very appreciative.

Comment: why do you want this information?

Comment: It probably doesn't have information you can read since all it does is take the button presses and translate them to IR pulses. It's most likely that this chip was built only for Roku